# body:before not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-class

I'm trying to 'fake' multiple backgrounds in IE8 using the :before pseudo class on the body element.

```
body {
    background: url('../image/header.gif') no-repeat center 50px;
}

body:before {
    content: '';
    background: url('../image/footer.gif') no-repeat center 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;

    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

I can't seem to get it to work though? IE just doesn't seem to recognise it at all neither in terms of displaying the 2nd background or showing the attributes in the developer tools.

Here is a link to the page too if that helps:
- http://www.concept.mattpealing.co.uk/grtsdfstvl-31-07-2014/dev/

Comment: I believe that `z-index` is not supported in IE8 for pseudo elements.

Comment: Try this 

    background-image: url('../image/footer.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

ie8 dont understand background-size Proof http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: For relatively positioned (pseudo-)block, `height:100%` will work only if the parent element (i.e. `body`) has explicit `height` value. It's better to position such pseudo element absolutely. Also, you can just set one background to `html` and another one to `body`.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn didn't cross my mind at all to set one as html and one as body! That works nicely, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to give the parent of a relatively positioned element  an explicit height, which is why `height:100%` on the `:before` will not work.

`positon:absolute` on the body will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
body:before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('../image/footer.gif');
    background-repear: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: @Avril - Its not clear how/why this is an answer. It looks like pealo86's original code that does not work. Could you explain it a bit?